# Bootstrap datepicker not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to setup bootstrap datepicker and it's not loading. I've setup a demo here on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/950g0oku/6/

The input field is

```
<input id="id_dates-0-starts" class="datepicker field_required" type="text" name="dates-0-starts">
```

and the javascript

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

I expect when I click the box the calendar should show. Using bootstrap datepicker from here https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: which date picker plugin you use ? you need to include pluing in external resource.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap datepicker

Comment: By default bootstarp don't have date picker component . you need to use plugin for datepicker

Comment: see working example here https://jsfiddle.net/950g0oku/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), you will have to include the library itself. I've updated your example so it works!

You were missing these library files:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/950g0oku/8/